# Integration on manifolds with boundary

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-topology

How can I define integral on manifolds with boundary? To use unity partition don't  have I to deal with open sets of the same type, I mean, how can I be sure that there is a unity partition on my atlas once I have open sets on $M$ and on $\partial M$?

Comment: Why would you pick open sets on $\partial M$? Just carry out the same partition of unity idea as usual; the main difference is that you'll now have charts homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ and some homeomorphic to the half-space $\Bbb H^n$. But you can integrate on both of those perfectly well.

Comment: so there is no difference? What I said was not good, I mean, the fact that there are open sets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^n$ does not change the existence of unity partiton, @MikeMiller?

Comment: Have you tried working through the details?

Comment: Nope. You can find a smooth partition of unity just the same. Indeed this should be carried out in most smooth manifolds books.

Comment: @Pedro, I was just wondering if will happen any problem. Now I see.

Comment: @MikeMiller, thank you so much. I have tried some, but not that I could understand completely, the most of them just said that would be everything fine.